# What does The non-generic method cannot be used with type arguments mean in this context?

Tags: c#

I have the following class and method:

```
public class UserManager<TUser, TKey> : IDisposable
    where TUser : class, global::Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<TKey>
    where TKey : global::System.IEquatable<TKey> {

   public virtual Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(TKey userId);
```

and:

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
```

I am trying to call this method like this:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync<ApplicationUser,int>(99);
```

It gives me the error:

The non-generic method

> 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(int)'
>   cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: In my case, i imported the wrong generic method (by letting IDE doing auto imports), wanted collection HashSet but imported bouncy castle HashSet which works completely differently.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the error says, `FindByIdAsync` does not take type parameters. These exist on the declaring class `UserManager<TUser, TKey>`

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(99);
```

Answer (score 12):

The method is declared as:

```
public virtual Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(TKey userId);
```

And not :

```
public virtual Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync<T, U>(TKey userId);
```

The method is not generic, so you cannot pass types when calling it.

The fix is by calling it without the types:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(99);
```